# Flutter: Scoped model and how to decide what and how much to put in files

Tags: architecture, dart, flutter

So, this is a more general kind of question. Recently, I was trying to figure out which architecture to use with flutter and I ended up with the scoped model, which I really like. But I noticed that I'm kinda tapping in the dark when it comes to deciding what information to put in the models and in general how much to put in each .dart file.

Do I just put data in there that will trigger state changes or everything non-gui?

And for the general oversight part: Currently I just write a module that I import and as the line count grows too big for my liking (oversight) I split it up into sub modules. I feel like this isn't really the best way to keep oversight and be efficient. How are you handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right answer to this, it's probably a question that should be asked on Reddit or in the Google group.

I would suggest you not to go overboard with "sub modules" and abstractions if there is no real benefit from it, especially on a high level. You can always do it at a later point.

Make sure that your methods aren't getting too long. For example, you can split up your `build` method into `buildAppBar`, `buildBody`, `buildFab`. The method names will add a lot of clarity to your code.

In general consistent naming is very important.

Don't be afraid of putting multiple related classes and methods into a single dart file (for comparison, look at Flutter's source code).

On a higher level, it makes sense to separate the business logic of your app from the widget layer. For example, avoid mixing animation code with code that calls a backend API.

If there is a lot of complex business logic or a complex data layer, you can introduce a service/data layer that consists of simple classes (e.g. `AccountService`, `WeatherDataRepository`). These services would be provided through `InheritedWidget`s and live as long as the app lives.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.